# Fabric.js small circle constrained to radius from center of canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js to create a small moveable circle, which is constrained at a radius about the center of the canvas.

I tried determine the horizontal and vertical absolute difference between the center of the small moveable circle and the center of the canvas. If value exceeded a 101px radius, position was not changed. If value, was less than 99px radius, position was not changed. Another technique tried was to reduce or increase small circle left and top position, until within 99-101.

Comment: hi can you post some work at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? so we will have better idea what you want

Comment: Please edit your question to include the attempted solution (a snippet with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally).